# NullReferenceException. Why?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a line:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
   checkID = collider.GetComponent<PartInfo>().ID;
}
```

That PartInfo.cs:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class PartInfo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] int id = 0;
    GameObject parent = null;

    public int ID { get { return id; } }
}
```

So I see this error on *"checkID ="* line. I don't understand why. Help me understand it, please :)

Comment: Two possibilities: 1. `compareCollider` is null. 2. Component `PartInfo` is null, i.e., the part info was not found. Either fix the underlying or write: `checkID = compareCollider?.GetComponent<PartInfo>()?.ID ?? 0;`

Comment: FWIW, the function parameter is called `collider` and you check for `compareCollider`.

Comment: You'll typically want to put a breakpoint on that line and check what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Thank you @olivier-jacot-descombes . There was no check for null.
I just added

```
if(collider.GetComponent<PartInfo>() != null)
   checkID =...
```

Comment: You will have to call `GetComponent` twice here. Consider using pattern matching: `if(collider.GetComponent<PartInfo>() is PartInfo pi) checkID = pi.ID;` or an empty property pattern which also checks for "not null": `if(collider.GetComponent<PartInfo>() is {} pi) checkID = pi.ID;` or `checkID = compareCollider.GetComponent<PartInfo>()?.ID ?? 0;` to assign `0` when not part was found.

Comment: Consider using `if (TryGetComponent(out PartInfo part) { checkID = part.ID; }` instead. This lets you check for the existence of the component and take a reference if it exists in one concise step. It also avoids an extra allocation in edit mode (`GetComponent` generates a dummy object to stand in for the `null` for better error reporting in-editor).